# Windows Server Backup and System State size

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-server-backup

I am currently using Windows Server Backup (on a Windows 2016 DC server) for daily backups of System State to a local network folder - ie the network folder is shared by the very same host I am backing up, and from here it is automatically copied onto a different storage server.

It is my understanding that System State backups done via Windows Server Backup and stored on a network folder (even a *local* network folder) always are *full backups*: WBS only supports incremental backup via VSS, so a local target is needed for incremental copies. Moreover, backups taken via a network share have no history (only the last backup is valid).

What I see, however, is that while *sometime* a full (~13 GB, with extensive changed file list) backup is taken, each subsequent backup is quite small (200-300 MB, with very few changed files). After some runs/days (for example, 7 days) a full backup is automatically taken, and from here, a new cycle of apparently incremental backups begin.

Granted that I am happy to use incremental backups, I would really like to understand *why and how* this is happening. Based on all online articles I read, each backup should be a full one, taking its fair share of space. Anyone with an explanation?